# how to decrement in parse server javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, ionic2, parse-server

in parse documentation there is something about increment

[parse server increment reference code](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.Object.html#methods_increment)

i need to achieve a decrement function to decrease the parse column by 1 each time this function is called but i can not find it in the documentation

here is my code

```
       // we will decerment unread count
   const ConversationObject = Parse.Object.extend("conversations");       
   var fromconvQuery = new Parse.Query(ConversationObject);         
   fromconvQuery.equalTo("from", this.currentUser);
   fromconvQuery.equalTo("to", this.to);

   var toconvQuery = new Parse.Query(ConversationObject);  
   toconvQuery.equalTo("from", this.to);
   toconvQuery.equalTo("to", this.currentUser);

   var mainconvQuery = Parse.Query.or(fromconvQuery, toconvQuery);
   mainconvQuery.first({
     success: function(conv){
      conv.decrement('unreadCount')
      conv.save()
     }
   })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is specify a negative amount:

```
conv.increment('unreadCount', -1);
conv.save();
```